# FCM notification send method token limit for bulk messages

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I herd that we can send only 1000 tokens for a Firebase push notification send method when we push notification as a bulk.

But I cannot find any reference in Firebase documentation for that limitation.

Does anyone knows the place where Firebase have mentioned it?

Comment: For bulk notifications you should use topics

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi Im talking about the maximum no. of devices that we can send notifications to from a single firebase request